# Optimizing algorithm to find number of six digit numbers satisfying certain property

Tags: c++, algorithm

Problem: "An algorithm to find the number of six digit numbers where the sum of the first three digits is equal to the sum of the last three digits."

I came across this problem in an interview and want to know the best solution. This is what I have till now.

Approach 1: The Brute force solution is, of course, to check for each number (between 100,000 and 999,999) whether the sum of its first three and last three digits are equal. If yes, then increment certain counter which keeps count of all such numbers.

But this checks for all 900,000 numbers and so is inefficient.

Approach 2: Since we are asked "how many" such numbers and not "which numbers", we could do better. Divide the number into two parts: First three digits (these go from 100 to 999) and Last three digits (these go from 000 to 999). Thus, the sum of three digits in either part of a candidate number can range from 1 to 27.
* Maintain a `std::map<int, int>` for each part where key is the sum and value is number of numbers (3 digit) having that sum in the corresponding part.
* Now, for each number in the first part find out its sum and update the corresponding map.
* Similarly, we can get updated map for the second part. 
* Now by multiplying the corresponding pairs (e.g. value in map 1 of key 4 and value in map 2 of key 4) and adding them up we get the answer.

In this approach, we end up checking 1K numbers.

My question is how could we further optimize? Is there a better solution?

Comment: "Optimize" is tricky.  Since there's no variable input, there's a correct O(1) program `{return const_value;}`, but I assume that's not what you want.

Comment: @ Ted: 000,000 (or 023,289) can't be considered a 6 digit number.

Comment: @ aschepler: I agree. But, I would consider "approach 2" an "optimization" over "approach 1", if that clears things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `0 <= s <= 18`, there are exactly `10 - |s - 9|` ways to obtain `s` as the sum of two digits.

So, for the first part

```
int first[28] = {0};
for(int s = 0; s <= 18; ++s) {
    int c = 10 - (s < 9 ? (9 - s) : (s - 9));
    for(int d = 1; d <= 9; ++d) {
        first[s+d] += c;
    }
}
```

That's 19*9 = 171 iterations, for the second half, do it similarly, with the inner loop starting at 0 instead of 1, that's 19*10 = 190 iterations. Then sum `first[i]*second[i]` for `1 <= i <= 27`.

Comment: You could also probably shave some by noting `second[27-i] == second[i]`, since if the sum of digits in `N` is `S`, the sum of digits in `999 - N` is `27 - S`.

Comment: Yes, good point. Makes the loop control a bit more complicated, but halves the iterations at the price of 14 copies/reflections.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best we can do. I would like to know how you came up with '10 - |s - 9|' idea. Just trying to understand the thought process :)

Comment: @NGambit For `s <= 9`, the first digit has `s+1` possibilities, and the second is determined by that. For `10 <= s <= 18`, it's the symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

Generate all three-digit numbers; partition them into sets based on their sum of digits. (Actually, all you need to do is keep a vector that counts the size of the sets). For each set, the number of six-digit numbers that can be generated is the size of the set squared. Sum up the squares of the set sizes to get your answer.

```
int sumCounts[28]; // sums can go from 0 through 27
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    sumCounts[sumOfDigits(i)]++;
}
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 28; ++i) {
    count = sumCounts[i];
    total += count * count;
}
```

**EDIT** Variation to eliminate counting leading zeroes:

```
int sumCounts[28];
int sumCounts2[28];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    int s = sumOfDigits(i);
    sumCounts[s]++;
    sumCounts2[s]++;
}
for (int i = 100; i < 1000; ++i) {
    sumCounts[sumOfDigits(i)]++;
}
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 28; ++i) {
    count = sumCounts[i];
    total += (count - sumCounts2[i]) * count;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly "Approach 2", if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Sort of, but it can be done with a simple int array; no need for a `std::map<int,int>`.

Comment: sums go from 1 to 27. 000,000 (or 023,289) can't be considered a 6 digit number. Due to the same reasoning, you can't just square the size of the set

Comment: @NGambit - Then something like your second alternative is the way to go. I've updated my code to show how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Python Implementation**

```
def equal_digit_sums():
dists = {}
for i in range(1000):
    digits = [int(d) for d in str(i)]
    dsum = sum(digits)
    if dsum not in dists:
        dists[dsum] = [0,0]
    dists[dsum][0 if len(digits) == 3 else 1] += 1
def prod(dsum):
    t = dists[dsum]
    return (t[0]+t[1])*t[0]
return sum(prod(dsum) for dsum in dists)

print(equal_digit_sums())
```

**Result: 50412**

Answer (score 0):

One idea: For each number from 0 to 27, count the number of three-digit numbers that have that digit sum. This should be doable efficiently with a DP-style approach.

Now you just sum the squares of the results, since for each answer, you can make a six-digit number with one of those on each side.

Comment: No, not the squares, the first three digits never start with a zero.

Comment: *not quite*, since the second half goes from 000-999.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Why isn't 000000 a six-digit number?

Comment: @TedHopp Normally, numbers don't have leading zeros. If they are allowed, however, taking squares is correct.

Comment: If it isn't allowed, then create *two* counts: one with and one without leading zeros. Then sum the products.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming leading 0's aren't allowed, you want to calculate how many different ways are there to sum to n with 3 digits. To calculate that you can have a for loop inside a for loop. So:

```
firstHalf = 0
for i in xrange(max(1,n/3),min(9,n+1)): #first digit
  for j in xrange((n-i)/2,min(9,n-i+1)): #second digit
    firstHalf +=1  #Will only be one possible third digit
secondHalf = firstHalf + max(0,10-|n-9|)
```

If you are trying to sum to a number, then the last number is always uniquely determined. Thus in the case where the first number is 0 we are just calculating how many different values are possible for the second number. This will be n+1 if n is less than 10. If n is greater, up until 18 it will be 19-n. Over 18 there are no ways to form the sum.
If you loop over all n, 1 through 27, you will have your total sum.

Comment: You're right. I forgot that you don't necessarily want to be ranging over 1 to n in the outer loop.